# What is the proper way of using dbContext along with Repositories and Services

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I recently discovered that I used DbContext badly.

I tried to have single instance of DbContext per app and injected it to DbServcies and next to Repositories.

```
var context = new DbEntities();
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IPaymentLogService>(() => new PaymentLogService(context));


public PaymentLogService(installmentsEntities context)
{
        _context = context;
        _paymentLogRepository = new PaymentLogRepository(context);
}
```

I have repository created as follows:

```
public PaymentLogRepository(DbEntities context)
{
        _context = context;
}
```

When adding row via Entity Framework like this:

```
public int Add(PaymentLog entity)
{
    _context.PaymentLogs.Add(entity);
    var affectedRows = _context.SaveChanges();

    return numberOfAddedItems;
}
```

My _context existed whole the time then it new about all pending changes done e.g via setter therefore I got additional updates in database.

What is good pattern of using dbContext.

Should I instantiated it per method/action, or per Service/Repository?

Comment: Per *unit of work*.  For example, in a web context this is likely per request.

Comment: As far as i know (and i am not a pro) there are different points of view on this. Some developers believes that you should instantiate your context in repository do whatever you want to do with entity but only ONE operation and dispose it straight away while others use Unit of work pattern that instantiates context, uses it and watches for changes. When it looks like all operation with this entity are completed it saves result and disposes context.  Both approaches to this problem has their pros and cons.